# How to find the kth largest eigenvalue of a matrix, taking into account the sign?

Tags: matrix

I have a real symmetric matrix `m` (i.e. its eigenvalues are all real).  `Eigenvalues[m, {k}]` will find the `k`th largest eigenvalue *by magnitude*.  How can I find the `k`th largest, taking the sign into account?  How can I find the corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: This question is hard to read/understand.  Consider rephrasing it.

Comment: I rewrote it a little. Actually the title is the whole story.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Looking at all the confusion below, it would have been useful to explicitly mention in the question that you need to take the sign into account (not largest/smallest based on magnitude).  You didn't mention that the matrix is symmetric and real either.  Please take the time to write up the question precisely, then I'll post a simple solution.  We are trying to make sure that the questions here are useful not only for the original asker but also for others in the future.

Comment: Okay, I tried to rephrase your question based on how I understood it.  Please check that this is what you meant, and whether my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 7):

In general, eigenvalues are not real.  When asking for the `k`th largest eigenvalue, by default Mathematica sorts eigenvalues based on magnitude.

When using the Arnoldi method, it is possible to specify how eigenvalues should be sorted: based on magnitude, the real part, or imaginary part.  This is described under the `Method` option of `Eigenvalues` [in the version 10 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html).

For example, let's create a real symmetric matrix:

```
m = RandomReal[1, 15 {1, 1}];
m = m + Transpose[m];
```

These are all the eigenvalues, sorted decreasingly by magnitude:

```
Eigenvalues[m]
(* {14.8003, 2.73255, -2.63109, -2.51576, 1.87506, -1.58716, \
1.43875, 1.243, -1.20684, -0.947984, 0.630826, -0.550382, 0.491025, \
0.283469, -0.0578321} *)
```

We can instead request the 3 largest by real part:

```
Eigenvalues[m, 3, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]
(* {14.8003, 2.73255, 1.87506} *)
```

Use `Eigensystem` the same way to obtain both eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer and edit. Your answer solved my problem.

Comment: There are still some questions. `"Arnoldi"` method seems can only get half of the eigenvalues for matrix, how can I get the smallest eigenvalues by this method.

Comment: @Simon.Z To take the smallest (negative) ones, you can take the eigenvalues of `-m` instead of `m`, then multiply them by -1.  The Arnoldi method will usually only work for getting the few largest (or few smallest) eigenvalues, so this is indeed a limitation/

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[rF];
rF[mat_, n_] := With[{es = Eigensystem[mat]},
  With[{m = Transpose@es, o = Ordering[N@First@es, {n}]}, First@m[[o]]]]

mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[mat] // N
(* {{16.1168,-1.11684,0.},{{0.283349,0.641675,1.},{-1.28335,-0.141675, 1.},{1.,-2.,1.}}} *)

rF[mat,1]
```

$$ \left\{-\frac{3}{2} \left(\sqrt{33}-5\right),\left\{\frac{1}{22} \left(-11-3 \sqrt{33}\right),\frac{1}{44} \left(11-3
   \sqrt{33}\right),1\right\}\right\}$$

```
rF[mat, 1] // N
(* {-1.11684,{-1.28335,-0.141675,1.}} *)

rF[mat, 2] // N
(* {0.,{1.,-2.,1.}} *)
rF[mat, 3] // N
(* {16.1168,{0.283349,0.641675,1.}} *)
```

Comment: Yeah, so the conclusion is there is no quick function to tackle this problem. I should write several lines to do this.

Comment: @Simon.Z, afaik right.

Answer (score 1):

You can get just the nth largest Eigenvalue using the syntax

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 5}]
Eigenvalues[m, {3}]
```

Observe that this returns the third largest eigenvalue (i..e, the one with the third largest Abs[]).

```
Eigenvectors[m, {3}]
```

gives the corresponding eigenvector. Accordingly, you can get the smallest eigenvalues/vectors with

```
Eigenvalues[m, {Length[m]}]
```

Comment: I find Eigenvalues[m,{3}] is actually Eigenvalues[m,3][[3]], it seems the result is wrong sometimes. Especailly when there are both positive and negative eigenvalues.

Comment: The eigenvalues are returned in sorted order, sorted by the Abs[]. That would be the normal meaning of "larger" and "smaller" when dealing with complex numbers. But this does remove the need to explicitly calculate them all.

Comment: What if I want to get n-th largest eigenvalues considering sign of values?

Comment: Then you'll need to sort them yourself. Eigenvalues are, in general, complex valued, and "sign" isn't something that nicely applies to complex-values. Is +5-10$i$ greater or less than -3+20$i$?

Comment: Well, symmetric matrix gives real eigenvalue all the time. And if I use Sort[], how to find the corresponding eigenstates?