# Find the smallest eigenvalue (not absolute value ) for a generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Related post 
[Find the eigenvector associated with the smallest eigenvalue, not smallest in magnitude](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44151/find-the-eigenvector-associated-with-the-smallest-eigenvalue-not-smallest-in-ma)

I tried to find the smallest eigenvalue for a generalized eigenvalue problem A c= \lambda B c (the default option is by absolute value)
by

---

a = {{1, 2, 0}, {2, 5, 3}, {0, 3, 9}};
b = {{1, 5, 3}, {5, 2, 0}, {3, 5, 0}};

n = 5; dimension = 3;
Eigenvalues[N[{a, b}], 3]

-n + Eigenvalues[  N[{ a + n IdentityMatrix[dimension],  b + n IdentityMatrix[dimension] }, 32  ] ]

---

It does not work. How to find smallest eigenvalue for a generalized eigenvalue problem?

P.S. In my case (before shifting N* Identity matrix), all eigenvalues are real.

Comment: One approach is to get an a priori estimate of largest in magnitude, and shift along positive real axis with a multiple of identity matrix so that the most negative eigenvalue becomes also the largest. This will only work if there are no complex ones that become larger still.

Comment: I tried to shift by  n IdentityMatrix[dimension] in both matrices $a$ and $b$, seems this prescription only works in eigenvalue not generalized eigenvalue problem..

Comment: If your eigenvalues are complex, how would you define the "smallest"--magnitude?

Comment: I guess I had not realized the general case would behave differently. I sent a link to the question to someone more knowledgeable, so maybe a better answer will emerge.

Comment: Sorry for confusing, in my case, all eigenvalues are real (before shifting N* Identity matrix).

Comment: [Does this help?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67541/12)

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, it works (with a=-a) for a and b are real and symmetric. b is positive, which is the actual case I am interested in. Thank you so much!